# What is the difference between Asyncio and Thread module in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-asyncio

I'm learning python and i'm confused between asyncio and Thread, when to use what, doesnt they both do the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

Asyncio  is a way of handling multiple I/O operations from simultaneous sources without using parallel code execution.

It's a solution  for a particular task, not for doing  general parallel processing.

Comment: **`Thread` module does not do parallel processing**